# Looking for a node module that can write excel files with multiple sheets

Tags: node.js

I want to write Excel files which will contain multiple sheets. I am using node module excel-export but it does not seem to support writing multiple sheets in one single file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the library I was looking for. xlsx module does support workbook with multiple sheets. With this module it is possible to read and write workbooks having multiple sheets.

Here is the link to the package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: Jump ahead to https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#working-with-the-workbook on that page.